# How to invoke py script from Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have just started using Flask for my web development awhile ago. I came across numbers of tutorial on how I am able to set up Flask easily. However, I wanted to run a python script upon clicking on an icon. Is there any tutorial out there that I can get linked to?

This is part of the HTML code that I wanted users to click and invoke the python scipt.

```
<a href="#" class="icon fa-vcard-o"><span class="label">Icon</span></a>
```

Appreciate any help here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to create a request to specific route when user clicks icon on your website.

Python:

```py
@app.route('/my-route')
def my_route():
    # Your code here...
```

HTML:

```html
<a href="#" class="icon fa-vcard-o"><span class="label">Icon</span></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
    for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
        icons[i].onclick = function () {
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert('request successful!');
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "/my-route", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an API using flask that accepts a post request, write JavaScript code to make a post request on the API on click of the link, invoke the script through your back-end.